# Having Difficulty Using Nokogiri to Pull <li> Element

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-scraping, nokogiri

I'm trying to develop a scraper to pull in content from NewEgg. I installed Nokogiri on Ruby on Rails and as far as I can tell it's working. However, I'm having difficulty pulling in a specific element that holds the pricing information and I'm not entirely sure why it isn't working. The code below should look for the list class "price-current " and put every instance of that code. Instead, I get no results.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'

page = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820313436"))   

page.xpath('//li[@class="price-current "]').each do |item|
  puts item
end
```

I've been tearing my hair out for the last two hours trying to figure this out with no success. Any insight would be much appreciated!

**EDIT:** So, @MarkReed was right about the information I'm looking for being generated by JS. Looking through the code, there appears to be a lot of detail that's in a hash. Is it possible to use RegEx in Nokogiri to pull that information?

```
  var utag_data = {
  page_breadcrumb:'Home &gt; Computer Hardware &gt; Memory &gt; Desktop Memory &gt; Team Group &gt; Item#:N82E16820313436',
        page_tab_name:'Computer Hardware',
        product_category_id:['17'],
        product_category_name:['Memory'],
        product_subcategory_id:['147'],
        product_subcategory_name:['Desktop Memory'],
        product_id:['20-313-436'],
        product_web_id:['N82E16820313436'],
        product_title:['Team Zeus Yellow 8GB (2 x 4GB) 240-Pin DDR3 SDRAM DDR3 1600 (PC3 12800) Desktop Memory Model TZYD38G1600HC9DC01'],
        product_manufacture:['Team Group'],
        product_unit_price:['79.99'],
        product_sale_price:['66.99'],
        product_default_shipping_cost:['0.01'],
        product_type:['Newegg'],
        product_model:['TZYD38G1600HC9DC01'],
        product_instock:['1'],
        product_group_id:['0'],
        page_type:'Product',
        site_region:'USA',
        site_currency:'USD',
        page_name:'ProductDetail',
        search_scope:jQuery('#haQuickSearchStore option:selected').text(),
        user_nvtc:Web.StateManager.Cookies.get(Web.StateManager.Cookies.Name.NVTC),
        user_name:Web.StateManager.Cookies.get(Web.StateManager.Cookies.Name.LOGIN,'LOGINID6'),
        third_party_render:['3cb31f7b6faf223eb237af8c737abcebce803020','4774d6780334a7bf9c3c95255c60401916d07cae','e3770e5b640207523c7ac0afed2237ce2f79cd27','9c3638f897ed4a655fd0bd839f04e1c412d54bff','78b8b16d9d0f6f2e8419ac12fa710f5153f1cee3','65531e14b4d9b9a223cc3bfcb65ce7b5f356011d','2a5e772a0f941c862180037f8a5c118c7abf2f7d','9011adc5233493f5adc5f0f0f1bcb655892c09e3']

  };
```

Comment: Well, on that URL, I don't see any elements with the "price-current" class?  In fact, the only prices I see are in Javascript code..

Comment: Hi @MarkReed - there is a list element on the site itself. See here(http://i.imgur.com/Dj0iRZx.png)

Comment: But if that is added by javascript code after the page loads, Nokogiri will never see it.

Comment: You may want to look at using [Watir](http://watir.com) to drive an actual browser and retrieve the DOM after the JS has run.

Comment: To answer your edit, you could theoretically use Nokogiri to grab the `<script>` elements and search their text for that object literal, and then try to use regexes to extract the data.  It would be messy and fragile, though.  That literal is not even valid JSON, so you couldn't use the `json` library to parse it into a Hash without doing some sort of regex-based surgery on it first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be searching for DOM elements which are dynamically added by Javascript in the browser after the page loads.  They do not exist in the HTML originally fetched from the URL, and so are not accessible to Nokogiri.